# Generics with Event automatically generated

Tags: c#, events, generics

I am trying to create a generic class. The class is going to have some generic events. Is it possible to create generic event handlers something like

```
class MyClass<T> 
{
    public event EventArgs SomeEventClass();
}
```

Where the class name for the EventClass is created by generics at the same time using a base class.

I am effectively trying to pass thing back in an event handler and would like them to be type safe to the caller.

Comment: It's not clear what you want exactly... Why do you need EventClass? What does it have to do with Generics?

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting something like this....

```
class MyClass<T> 
{
   public event EventHandler<EventArgs<T>> SomeEvent;

   protected void RaiseEvent(T data)
   {
      var tmp = SomeEvent;
      if(tmp != null)
         tmp(this, new EventArgs<T>(data));
    }
}
```

You will need to create the generic `EventArgs` but that should be easy.
You can derive the base class and call the `RaiseEvent` method using the specific generic argument

Answer (score 0):

Names can't be specified with generics in any context. They are use to specify *types*.

Code generation might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I believe the OP doesn't want “generic” name, even though the code sample may indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
class MyClass<T> 
{
    public event Func<T> GenericEvent;
}
```

Comment: All events should follow the standard EventHadler pattern, so that they are compatible with other code.